# Working with HtmlAgilityPack, nested List and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

```
List<List<string>> table = playerDoc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode($"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[4]/table/tbody")
    .Descendants("tr")
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

I have this code block which gathers all the correct information from a table on a website. My issue is the data looks like this:

[image: data]

I'm trying to figure out how to search the data for 2 matching strings, for example `S16` and `Pre` and be able to set a class called `CareerProperties` (a class of props I can post if needed). I have tried different variations of the `LINQ` statement and using a `foreach` loop but I either get exceptions thrown or I get everythign in the table.

I'm trying to simplify my code as it takes around 3-4 seconds to retrieve the data using a `foreach` with `xpaths`, and when I tested the `LINQ` statement it came back as Elapsed: 00:00:00.0068306.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm still learning `C#` and such.  If I need to post a sample web page or any other part of the code I will do so.  Thank you.

Edit:

```
foreach (var careerStats in findCareerNode)
{
    if (careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode($"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[1]").InnerText.Trim() != seasonId)
    {
        index++;
        continue;
    }
    else if (careerStats
       .SelectSingleNode(
           $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[2]")
       .InnerText.Trim() != "Reg")
    {
        index++;
        continue;
    }
    var type = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[2]")
        .InnerText;
    var record = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[3]")
        .InnerText;
    var amr = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[4]")
        .InnerText ?? "0.0";
    var goals = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[5]")
        .InnerText;
    var assists = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[6]")
        .InnerText;
    var sot = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[7]")
        .InnerText;
    var shots = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[8]")
        .InnerText;
    var passC = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[9]")
        .InnerText;
    var passA = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[10]")
        .InnerText;
    var keypass = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[11]")
        .InnerText;
    var interceptions = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[12]")
        .InnerText;
    var tac = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[13]")
        .InnerText;
    var tacA = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[14]")
        .InnerText;
    var blk = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[15]")
        .InnerText;
    var rc = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[16]")
        .InnerText;
    var yc = careerStats
        .SelectSingleNode(
            $"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[{div}]/table/tbody/tr[{index}]/td[17]")
        .InnerText;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the next information: **1.** what filter you want to apply to each row of the table (`for example "S16" and "Pre"`); **2.** add `CareerProperties` class and describe how to map `td` items to properties of this class?

Comment: I can add how i'm doing it with the foreach, for the TD map I'm trying to map for eg: Season to CareerProperties season so in the next part of my application I can do data.Season.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter data of the career stats table you can use LINQ method [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__). And then filtered data can be used to create list of `CareerProperties` objects using LINQ method [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__).

Here is how we can get career stats for selected `seasonId` and `Reg`:

```
// Now the return type is a List of CareerProperties.
List<CareerProperties> table = playerDoc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode($"//*[@id='lg_team_user_leagues-{leagueId}']/div[4]/table/tbody")
    .Descendants("tr")
    .Skip(1)
    // Up to here is your code. Here you select all rows from the table.
    // Each row is presented as List<string>.
    .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
    // Here we filter table rows by "seasonId" and "Reg".
    .Where(tr => tr[0] == seasonId && tr[1] == "Reg")
    // Here we create objects CareerProperties from filtered rows.
    .Select(tr => new CareerProperties
        {
            Type = tr[2],
            Record = tr[3],
            Amr = tr[4],
            Goals = tr[5]
            Assists = tr[6],
            // Fill other properties.
            ...
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hey, Iliar I'm having an issue using this for something similar.  The table has a thead in the middle of it, which causes  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range error.  Do you mind helping me once again to figure out how to fix it?

Comment: Here is the table: https://www.leaguegaming.com/forums/index.php?leaguegaming/league&action=league&page=standing&leagueid=53&seasonid=18

The LINQ statement errors when it reaches the 2nd "thead" in the table no matter what I do. Here's the statement https://gist.github.com/compil3/e0d61876cb03c451cf7bedae8aa5a38a  I can't figure out how to either skip the 2nd 'thead' or another way of doing it.  Thank you btw.

Comment: Try to replace next code `.SelectSingleNode("//*@id='content']/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/table").Descendants("tr").Skip(2)` with the next `.SelectNodes("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr")`. Xpath `//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr` selects rows with team stats.